# registered a NHibernate proxy factory fot IDataErrorInfo behavoir with lazy properties

Tags: validation, nhibernate, castle-dynamicproxy

I have implemented IDataErrorInfo interface using Castle.DynamicProxy IIterceptor. I have also implemented a NHibernate interceptor which instantiates my entities using this interceptor.

I wish to implement IDataErrorInfo for lazyload proprerties as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525046/implementing-idataerrorinfo-using-castle-dynamicproxy-in-lazy-loading-scenario-u)

In the link above the solution required to register DataBindingProxyFactory as NHibernate proxy factory

I use NH 3.2 and don't know how and where register this

Can anyone hel me?

thanks to all

Comment: .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty(Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, typeof(DataBindingProxyFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName)) 

[thanks to João Manso][1]

  [1]: http://joao.manso.eu/index.php/2011/08/how-to-upgrade-your-apps-to-nhibernate-3-2-with-fluent-nhibernate-1-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty(Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, typeof(DataBindingProxyFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName))
```

thanks to João Manso][1] [1]: joao.manso.eu/index.php/2011/08/… – guton Sep 9 '12 at 13:35